# Order Statistic as a Consistent Estimator

Tags: statistics, solution-verification

**Problem.** Let $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ denote a random sample from the distribution with common pdf
$$ f(x;\theta) = e^{-(x-\theta)} 1_{(\theta,+\infty)}(x), \;\; \theta \in \mathbb{R} $$
Let $Y_{n} = \min \{X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}\}$. Is $Y_{n}$ a consistent estimator of $\theta$?

**Attempt.** Note that if $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}[|Y_n - \theta| < \epsilon]=1$, then $Y_n$ is a consistent estimator for $\theta$. The CDF of $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ is

\begin{align*}
F(x) &= \int_{0}^{x} e^{-(t-\theta)} \, dt \\
&= e^{\theta-x}(e^x-1) && x \in (\theta, \infty)
\end{align*}
So $F_{Y_n}(x) = [e^{\theta-x}(e^x-1)]^n$. Moreover,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}[|Y_n - \theta| < \epsilon] &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}[\theta - \epsilon < Y_n < \epsilon + \theta] \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}  [F_{Y_n}(\theta + \epsilon) - F_{Y_n}(\theta - \epsilon)] \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} (e^{-\epsilon}(\epsilon^{\theta+\epsilon}-1))^{n} \\
&= \infty
\end{align*}
So $Y_n$ is not a consistent estimator for $\theta$. Is this correct?

Comment: How could $P[|Y_n - \theta| < \epsilon] \rightarrow \infty?$ It's always $\leq 1$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom This pdf requires the minimum if it is to make sense, often written $X_{(1)}$ though $Y_n$ might help with $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\,$

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by user51547, we cannot have $P[|Y_n - \theta| < \epsilon] \rightarrow \infty$ to there should be a mistake somewhere, and actually it is already a the stage of the computation of the c.d.f. of $X_1$ since with the current expression, we have $\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)=e^{\theta}$ instead of $1$.

We can proceed as follow: first, since $X_i\geqslant \theta$ almost surely, we derive that $\{\lvert Y_n-\theta\rvert>\varepsilon\}=\{ Y_n>\theta+\varepsilon\}$ hence
$$
\mathbb P\{\lvert Y_n-\theta\rvert>\varepsilon\}=\mathbb P\left\{ \min_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i>\theta+\varepsilon\right\}=\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i>\theta+\varepsilon\}\right).
$$
Then use independence and compute $\mathbb P(X_1>\theta+\varepsilon)$.